# Lint is saying SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabas() may produce NullPointerException

Tags: android

The Lint is saying I can get a `NullPointerException` when I:

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sqlStatement);
```

I've looked into [SQliteOpenHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked%28boolean%29) class and didn't find any evidence this call can be resulted in this exception, can you guys elaborate?

Comment: Lint always knows better :P CHeck again

Comment: Which lint tool are you using? I cannot reproduce this with ADT 22.0.5 lint running on default settings.

Answer (score 2):

Method getWritableDatabase() has to be called on Object of class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. It seems like you are invoking with in the same class, create it object and then invoke.

You can read here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

You can ignore Lint Warnings regarding to this, and please consider Lint warnings regarding to strings and other warnings.

Comment: I'm invoking the method within the class which extends from SQLiteOpenHelper, why shall I create another object?